# Javascript class system using prototypes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm trying to create a 'class like' inheritance system in JS using functions and prototypes.
The idea is to achieve something similar to ExtJS class system without the overhead of the entire framework.

So by now I created an `ObjectBase` function, modified its prototype to contain some shared functionalities
and wrote an `injectProto()` function to merge two functions prototypes (in a loop).

Here's the `injectProto()` code

```
/**
 * Injects a function's prototype into another function's prototype.
 * 
 * @param  {Function} fn1   The function to inject into
 * @param  {Function} fn2   The function to inject from
 * @return {Function}       The injected function
 */
function injectProto(fn1, fn2) {
    for (var m in fn2.prototype) {

        Object.defineProperty(fn1.prototype, m, {
            value: fn2.prototype[m]
        });
    }

    fn1.prototype.constructor = fn1;
    fn1.prototype.parent = fn2.prototype;

    return fn1;
}
```

And the `ObjectBase` code

```
/**
 * Base Object, provides shared functionalities.
 * 
 * [!] All functions extend this one
 * 
 */
var ObjectBase = function(){
};
var ObjectBase.prototype = {
    constructor: ObjectBase,
    parent: none,
    listeners: [],

    addListener: function(listener) {
        this.listeners.push(listener);
    },
    getListeners: function() {
        return this.listeners;
    },
    removeListener: function(listener) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.listeners.length; i++) {
            if (listener === this.listeners[i]) {
                this.listeners.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now, the problem.

If I create a 'subclass' using `injectProto` and make new instances of it, they all share the same reference to the
`listeners` property.

So if I add a listener to a subclass instance (foo) every other instance (bar) gets a new listener.

```
// 1. Inject ObjectBase proto into an empty function
var Foo = injectProto(function(){}, ObjectBase);

// 2. Make some instances
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Foo();

// 3. Add a dummy listener to foo
foo.addListener( function(){ console.log("I'm Batman!") } );

// 4. Appreciate my confusion
console.log( foo.getListeners() );
console.log( bar.getListeners() );
```

Output:

```
[function()]
[function()]  // Should be empty (?)
```

Why is that? I did assign every single property from one prototype to the other inside `injectProto`. Could anyone help me here?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use ES6 (which gives you fake classes) or Resig's Simple Inheritance? Or my personal favorite approach, _stop trying to use classical inheritance in a prototypical language._

Comment: Just so you know, Classes are being standardized in ECMAScript 6 ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes))

Comment: I've been away from JS from a while now, i llok into ES6, thanks.

@Mathletics "...stop trying to use classical inheritance in a prototypical language...", it's usually my approach too until I find myself doing it anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions, you have the property `listeners` set *on the prototype*, so it is shared by all instances. Your constructor needs to create this property on each instance object instead.

```
function ObjectBase() {
  this.listeners = [];
  this.parent = 'none'; // you have `parent: none` which will error as `none` is undefined
}
```

---

As an aside, don't use `delete` to remove elements from an array; you'll muck up the indexes. Use a proper array method like `splice`. Also, don't use `for..in` on arrays.

Comment: Mh. Ok.
" ...Use a proper array method like splice. Also, don't use for..in on arrays."
Thank you, I wrote the snippets in a rush I'll amend the question code